# Can't call class functions from main, "is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to learn react by creating a simple weather app which uses api requests to get the data. The api requires a location key which can be obtained through another function. this means i have to return and then pass the key along to the next function but I seem to be having some trouble doing this!

> ```
> TypeError: _LocationKey__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.setLocation is not a function" is the error i am given when I attempt to run.
> ```

I'm assuming I made an error with how i am calling the functions as well as how the actual classes are structured. Any help would be appreciated!

```
//The main app
function App() {

  //runs function to set api location key
  new LocationKey();
  LocationKey.setLocation('winnipeg');

  //uses get location key to set weatherData
  new Weather();
  Weather.getWeatherData(LocationKey.getLocation());

  //displays location and weather information 
  return (
    <div className="body">
          <LocationKey/>
          <Weather/>
    </div>
  );
}

//The location key class
export class LocationKey extends Component{

  state = {
    locations: []
  }

  setLocation(name) {
    axios.get('http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?apikey=oqAor7Al7Fkcj7AudulUkk5WGoySmEu7&q=' + name + '&language=en&details=false')
      .then(res => {
        const locations = res.data;
        this.setState({ locations });
      })
  }

  getLocation(){
      return this.state.locations[0].Key;
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        { this.state.locations.slice(0, 1).map(location => <li>{location.EnglishName}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
export default LocationKey

//Weather Class
export class Weather extends Component{

  state = {
    weatherData: []
  }

  //issues command to find weather data from api using location key
  getWeatherData(location) {
    axios.get('http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/' + location + '?apikey=oqAor7Al7Fkcj7AudulUkk5WGoySmEu7&language=en&details=false&metric=true%20HTTP/1.1')
      .then(res => {
        const weatherData = res.data;
        this.setState({ weatherData });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        { this.state.weatherData.slice(0, 2).map(weather => <li>{weather.Headline.Text}</li>)}
        { this.state.weatherData.slice(0, 2).map(weather => <li>{weather.Headline.Category}</li>)}
        { this.state.weatherData.slice(0, 2).map(weather => <li>{weather.DailyForecasts.Maximum.Value}</li>)}
        { this.state.weatherData.slice(0, 2).map(weather => <li>{weather.DailyForecasts.Minimum.Value}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
export default Weather
```

Comment: `new LocationKey(); LocationKey.setLocation('winnipeg');` is the issue. You're instantiating a new instance of LocationKey, but then attempting to call a non-static function - which is invalid. Instead, you should probably be using props and passing the value to the component

Comment: @DerekPollard any chance you could provide me with an example of how I could do that? (I started using react yesterday so I have very little clue as to how props work)

Comment: Yeah, trying to write an example now

Comment: please provide `Weather` component too

Comment: @DerekPollard okay done! (the return might not work haven't tested it yet)

Comment: I'm sorry man. There's a lot going on here and it seems like you're missing a lot of the fundamentals for react. I suggest you going through their website and tutorials

Comment: @DerekPollard Thanks anyway, ill do some more reading...

Comment: @DerekPollard by shear coincidence there happens to be a video tutorial of a guy using the same api service and doing the exact same thing i am attempting to do haha [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=204C9yNeOYI)

Comment: Nice, I provided a rudimentary example below for you. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

The issue lies with this line:

```
LocationKey.setLocation('winnipeg');
```

You instantiate a new instance of `LocationKey`, but seeing as `LocationKey` isn't a singleton and `setLocation` is not a static method, you're trying to call an instance method in a static way.

Another potential issues is this line:

```
Weather.getWeatherData(LocationKey.getLocation());
```

As I said above, you instantiate a new instance of `Weather`, but since it isn't doing anything and isn't assigned to anything, it gets immediately thrown away, so the following line has no effect on it.

### The solution

I would suggest making App its own component and having it contain the state for the locations, then passing the locations array to each of the components.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    locations: ['winnipeg'],
    locationInput: ''
  };

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <input value={this.state.locationInput} onChange={e => this.setState({ locationInput: e.target.value })} />
        <button onClick={this.handleAddLocation}>add to locations</button>
        <Weather locations={this.state.locations} />
        <LocationKey locations={this.state.locations} />
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  handleAddLocation = () => {
    if (this.state.locationInput === '') return;
    this.setState({
      locationInput: '',
      locations: [...this.state.locations, this.state.locationInput]
    });
  };
}

class Weather extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    locations: []
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Weather Component</h2>
        <h3>Locations provided:</h3>
        <span>{this.props.locations.join(', ')}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class LocationKey extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    locations: []
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>LocationKey Component</h2>
        <h3>Locations provided:</h3>
        <span>{this.props.locations.join(', ')}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > ,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

In the above snippet, I set out to show you how props can be used and provided to child components.

I hope this can help and clarify some of this issues you've been having

Comment: Very helpful, and incredibly fast response

Comment: @blujay - glad I could help!